# animated plot over static plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, numerical-methods

I am trying to animate the processes of **dekker's method of root finding**

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation 
from IPython import display

# function definition
def function(x):
    
    return x**3 - x**2 - x - 1

# driver program
def drekker(a,b,tol):
    # a,b contains the root

    # all the relevant data for animation
    adata = []
    bdata = []
    cdata = []
    sdata = []
    mdata = []
    bndata = []
    
    # b to be better choice, we want the roots to close to b than a, that we make b's trend to go to f(b)~0 
    # so to ensure that we will swap in case |f(a)|>|f(b)|
    if abs(function(a)) < abs(function(b)):
        a = a+b
        b = a-b
        a = a-b
    
    c = a # initially but it will store previous value of b
    
    err = np.inf
    
    i = 0 # number of iteration
    while err > tol:
        
        i = i + 1
        # midpoint
        m = (a+b)/2
    
        # finding roots
        #(a)
        if abs(function(b)-function(c)) != 0: # seccant method converge
            s = b - function(b)*(c-b)/(function(c)-function(b))
        #(b)
        else:    # seccant method diverges       
            s = m
        adata.append(a)
        bdata.append(b)
        cdata.append(c)
        sdata.append(s)
        mdata.append(m)
        
        # new a,b,c
        c = b # c becomes the old b
        
        if abs(b-m) > abs(s-m):
            b = s
        else:
            b = m
        bndata.append(b)
        if function(b)*function(a) > 0:
            a = c
            
        err = abs(b-a)
    return s,adata,bdata,cdata,sdata,mdata,bndata
```

running the program by

```
_,a,b,c,s,m,bn=drekker(1,2,1e-7)
```

**The code gives accurate value of root**

to animate i did this

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
x = np.linspace(-2,4,100)
```

**this is the static plot**

```
ax.plot(x,y,'y') 
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0.5))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.set_xlim([0, 3])
ax.set_ylim([-2.5, 2])
```

**new plots will be made over the static one by deleting the previous one**

```
def animate(frame):  
    ax.plot([a[frame]],[function(a[frame])],'ko')
    ax.plot([b[frame]],[function(b[frame])],'ko')
    ax.plot([a[frame],b[frame]],[function(a[frame]),function(b[frame])],'r')

    ax.plot([s[frame]],[frame],'go')
    ax.plot([m[frame]],[frame],'bo')

    ax.annotate('a',(a[frame]-.1,function(a[frame])+.2))
    ax.annotate('b',(b[frame]-.1,function(b[frame])+.2))
    ax.annotate('c',(c[frame]+.1,function(c[frame])-.2))
    ax.annotate('s',(s[frame]-.03,.2))
    ax.annotate('m',(m[frame]-.02,.2))
    
anim = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=5, interval=2000)

video = anim.to_html5_video()
html = display.HTML(video)
display.display(html)
plt.close()
```

The whole idea is to show how a,b,c and the other values are changing to compute the root.
my problem is previous **a,b,c,s** etc plots are not getting **deleted**

Comment: The guy was named like a plank, not like dirt, 'Dekker".  //  In the `animate` function you should only use `set_data` on existing graphical objects, these obviously will need to be constructed before the animation. See any documentation examples.

Comment: Sorry about the name, a typo. set_data takes co-ordinateslike (x,y). I can call set_data on points like a,b,s? how about the secant line?